# How to get odd and even value from new int C#

Tags: c#, int

Hello that is my homework from the course for begginers, and I have no idea how to take the first input i than the second, not the numbers typed but the simple i. e.g.

2
  3
4 
  4
3
  1

I want to separate them somehow. But with this code it only takes :

1
1
  2
3
  4
  4etc..
And the source.

```
 Console.Write("Enter number of the numbers: ");
        int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] numbers = new int[a];
        int even = 1;
        int odd = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0)
            {
                even *= numbers[i];
            }
            else if (numbers[i] % 2 !=0)
            {
                odd *= numbers[i];
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine(odd);
        Console.WriteLine(even);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to count even and odd numbers?

Comment: Do you want to count the number of odd/even numbers or just to let user know if input is odd/even

Answer (score 1):

The way your application is written, it expects a single number to be entered (followed by the Enter key) indicating how many numbers in total will be read.

Then, it loops that many times, expecting a single number (followed by the Enter key) to be input for each loop.

That should be fine and work well.  However, if you want to enter all of the numbers at once, you will need to restructure things a bit.

You don't need `numbers` to be an array.  You never reference the value after you store it.  You can use just an integer.

You are multiplying your count rather than adding it, e.g.

```
even *= numbers[i];
```

should be

```
even++;
```

if you want to count the number of even numbers, or

```
even += numbers[i];
```

if you want to sum them.

Same for tracking the odd number count.

Comment: That's not counting, that summing.

Comment: Heh oopps.  Need more coffee.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Not clear what the OP wants, so I edited to present both options.